# How can list blob file from MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to list blob from MySQL using PHP, but images are not showing. I checked on the source page, source page result are given below.

`data-url="<?php echo $eachImage; ?>"` & `data-thumbnail-path="<?php echo $eachImage; ?>"` here I am expecting path. In view source page this section is showing some encripted data.

How can I get the image path from blob file?

```
<?php foreach ($this->carousel as $carousel): ?>

        <?php 
             if ($carousel['title'] == 'service') {
                $rs = Database::getInstance()
                      ->query("SELECT * FROM tl_carousel WHERE title = 'service' ");

                $result = $rs->fetchAllAssoc(); 
                $images = deserialize( $carousel['themesSRC'] );
                foreach ($images as $eachImage)
                {

                ?>

                <ul>
                    <li data-url="<?php echo $eachImage; ?>" data-width="800" data-height="500"></li>
                    <li data-thumbnail-path="<?php echo $eachImage; ?>"></li>
                    <li data-thumbnail-text="" data-thumbnail-text-title-offset="43" data-thumbnail-text-offset-top="16" data-thumbnail-text-offset-bottom="7">
                    <!-- <p class="largeLabel">CUSTOM TEXT CAN BE ADDED HERE</p> -->
                    <p class="smallLabel"><?php echo $carousel['title']; ?></p>
                    </li>

                    <li data-info="">
                    <!-- <p class="mediaDescriptionHeader">CUSTOM TEXT CAN BE ADDED HERE AND FORMATTED WITH CSS</p> -->
                    <p class="mediaDescriptionText"><?php echo $carousel['title']; ?></p>
                    </li>       
                </ul>

                <?php
                }
             } 
        ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**View source Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to access images from blob, you use :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($eachImage).'"/>
```

-> image/png for a png, or image/jpeg for a jpeg

> Related (don't know if you'll need it, but worth reading)

- [Image Processing and Generation](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php)